# AngularJS $interpolate error text.indexOf while compiling template

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to compile a template in a service in AngularJS, but I keep receiving this error when I use the $compile service:

```
text.indexOf is not a function
```

I've tried a few different approaches, but I can't seem to get a working solution. There is a working fiddle though: http://jsfiddle.net/DUM7t/ So I have no clue why it's breaking. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
If I place the snipping contents in a run block in my application it works aswell.

Service:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .service('PrintUtilService', PrintUtilService);

  PrintUtilService.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$timeout', '$interpolate', '$templateRequest', '$uibModal', 'APP', 'FORMATS'];
  /* @ngInject */
  function PrintUtilService($rootScope, $timeout, $compile, $templateRequest, $uibModal, APP, FORMATS) {
    var service = {
      printTemplate: printTemplate
    };

    return service;

    function printTemplate(){
      var data = ["1","2"];
      var html  =
        '<div>' +
        '<ul>' +
        '<li ng-repeat="score in data">{{score}}</li>' +
        '</ul>'+
        '</div>';

      var el = angular.element(html);

      $rootScope.data = data;
      var result = $compile(el)($rootScope); // error on this line

      $timeout(function() {
        console.log(el.html());
        alert(el.html());
      });
    }
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var scope = $rootScope.$new();
scope.data = data;
var result = $compile(el)(scope);
```

Comment: try add track by to your ngrepeat: '<li ng-repeat="score in data track by $index">{{score}}</li>'

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: After adding track by $index I still get the same error